# How to store multiple results in one table only MySql and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to generate Hourly Report using MySQL and PHP.

I want to show how many cases came in between 08:00:00 - 09:00:00 like this of 24 hours and Divide it Date Wise. Right now I am getting the result but I have created multiple result queries like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(IST_In_Time), DATE(IST_In_Time) FROM spillreport WHERE TIME (IST_In_Time) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '20:00:00' GROUP BY DATE(IST_In_Time)");
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(IST_In_Time), DATE(IST_In_Time) FROM spillreport WHERE TIME (IST_In_Time) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00' GROUP BY DATE(IST_In_Time)");
```

And storing it different while loops:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DATE(IST_In_Time)'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(IST_In_Time)'] . "</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DATE(IST_In_Time)'] . "</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(IST_In_Time)'] . "</td>";
}
```

I know this bad practice, but I don't have time to take a better approach. I want to display in a single table where rows will automatically increase according to dates and columns will be predefined like 7:00am-8:00am , 8:00am-9:00am and so on..

**EDIT:**
Using Below Answers I got the following Result:

Query: `SELECT DATE(IST_In_Time) date,HOUR(IST_In_Time) hour,COUNT(*) count FROM spillreport WHERE DATE(IST_In_Time)>= '2014-07-22 00:00:00' AND DATE(IST_In_Time)<= '2014-07-26 00:00:00' GROUP BY HOUR(IST_In_Time), DATE(IST_In_Time) ORDER BY DATE(IST_In_Time)ASC`

### Result:

```
date    hour    count
2014-07-22  19  1
2014-07-22  14  1
2014-07-23  18  28
2014-07-23  15  1
2014-07-23  19  26
2014-07-23  17  1
2014-07-23  20  8
2014-07-24  11  34
2014-07-24  19  2
2014-07-24  8   1
2014-07-24  12  35
2014-07-24  13  23
2014-07-24  15  37
2014-07-24  14  52
2014-07-24  10  34
2014-07-24  16  59
2014-07-24  9   15
2014-07-24  17  46
2014-07-24  18  25
2014-07-25  8   1
2014-07-26  19  1
2014-07-26  8   2
```

---

But I want to group only unique dates and hours should be divided horizontally like this:

```
    Hours 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    
2014-07-22 - - - - - - - - - - -  -   -  -  1  -  -  -  -  1  -  -  -  -
2014-07-23 - - - - - - - - - - -  -   -  -  -  1  - 1 28  26  8  -  -  -
2014-07-24
2014-07-25
2014-07-26
```

Like this!

**EDIT 2:**

```
select client_id,
  max(case when rownum = 1 then date end) Date1,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then date end) Date2,
  max(case when rownum = 3 then date end) Date3
from
(
  select client_id,
    date,
    @row:=if(@prev=client_id, @row,0) + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=client_id 
  from yourtable, (SELECT @row:=0, @prev:=null) r
  order by client_id, date
) s
group by client_id
order by client_id, date
```

I got this code to create pivot table, can anybody guide me how do I create this for mine?

Comment: Using the MySQL HOUR() function to group by may be useful.

Comment: You can do this a few ways. Firstly, my favourite way is to alter the SQL by doing a union, see one of the answers provided below. Secondly,  could you not change the `$row` variable on the second query and loop to `$row1` to avoid confusion. (Sorry I couldn't test that last part since I'm running low on time :(

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Unions are useful, though not here as it seems that the OP should not be using multiple queries in the first place. Multiple queries can often be replaced by a bit of education and then a single one, which the OP seems to realise hence the question. Hopefully the OP can clarify the question further if grouping by hour doesn't do it for him/her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want counts by the hour, so as commented you can use HOUR. e.g. to count number of events per hour today from a table I have to hand:

```
 mysql> SELECT DATE(event_time) date,HOUR(event_time) hour,COUNT(*) count 
   FROM events WHERE event_time > curdate() GROUP BY DATE(event_time),HOUR(event_time);
 +------------------+------------------+----------+
 | date             | hour             | count    |
 +------------------+------------------+----------+
 | 2014-07-26       |                0 |       30 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                1 |       21 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                2 |       11 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                3 |       29 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                4 |       25 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                5 |       22 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                6 |       46 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                7 |       42 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                8 |       26 |
 | 2014-07-26       |                9 |       58 |
 | 2014-07-26       |               10 |       11 |
 +------------------+------------------+----------+
 11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit: Updated to add missing grouping by date.

I'd suggest grouping by date,hour and ordering by date,hour too to get a nicely ordered result set. That should produce the data you need for any post processing in PHP. After that it's a PHP formatting job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union to (as is obvious) union the result set of different queries :

```
SELECT * FROM t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM t2
```

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).